# Add array table constraints, empty or null if other column is false

Tags: postgresql, constraint, check-constraints

I'm adding constraint on an existing table `jobs`:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS jobs CASCADE;
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS job_state;
CREATE TYPE job_state AS ENUM ( 'UNSTARTED', 'STARTED', 'FAILED', 'COMPLETED' );
CREATE TABLE jobs(
status job_state NOT NULL DEFAULT 'UNSTARTED',
error_message text[]
);

ALTER TABLE jobs
ADD CONSTRAINT error_message_is_null_if_failed_is_false 
   CHECK ( status IN ('UNSTARTED', 'STARTED', 'COMPLETED') AND ( error_message IS NULL OR error_message = '{}' ));
```

What I want is

```
INSERT INTO jobs VALUES ('UNSTARTED', null);
INSERT INTO jobs VALUES ('STARTED', null);
INSERT INTO jobs VALUES ('FAILED', null); -- I would like to be able to do this
```

I know this `error_message != '{}' OR error_message IS NOT NULL` is not written properly. But I'm stuck finding a way to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraint should be written using an `OR` like `(NOT A) OR B`

```
ALTER TABLE jobs
ADD CONSTRAINT error_message_is_null_if_failed_is_false 
   CHECK ( NOT ( status IN ('UNSTARTED', 'STARTED', 'COMPLETED')) OR ( error_message IS NULL OR error_message = '{}' ));

INSERT INTO jobs VALUES ('UNSTARTED', null); -- no error
INSERT INTO jobs VALUES ('STARTED', null); -- no error
INSERT INTO jobs VALUES ('FAILED', null); -- no error
INSERT INTO jobs VALUES ('COMPLETED', null); -- no error

INSERT INTO jobs VALUES ('UNSTARTED', '{}'); -- no error
INSERT INTO jobs VALUES ('STARTED', '{}'); -- no error
INSERT INTO jobs VALUES ('FAILED', '{}'); -- no error
INSERT INTO jobs VALUES ('COMPLETED', '{}'); -- no error

INSERT INTO jobs VALUES ('UNSTARTED', '{"error message"}'); -- error
INSERT INTO jobs VALUES ('COMPLETED', '{"error message"}'); -- error
INSERT INTO jobs VALUES ('STARTED', '{"error message"}'); -- error
INSERT INTO jobs VALUES ('FAILED', '{"error message"}'); -- no error
```

Answer (score -1):

Why are you doing

```
CHECK ( NOT (failed IS FALSE AND (error_message != '{}' OR error_message IS NOT NULL)) );
```

And not

```
CHECK (
  failed IS FALSE
  AND (error_message = '{}' OR error_message IS NULL )
);
```

Or, even better rather than keeping state across multiple booleans like `failed` and `error_message` use a single ENUM.

```
CREATE TYPE terminal_job_state AS ENUM ( 'FAILED', 'COMPLETED' )
```

Comment: Thanks but with your answer `INSERT INTO jobs VALUES (false, true, null);` raise and error `violates check constraint "error_message_is_null_if_failed_is_false"`.

Comment: But good idea for the enum. Didn't think about it